# Safar Month and Safety of beings from Jinns

Tags: quran, reference-request

Some of people around me think that month of safar is unsafe, when asked how, they say Jinns (ghost) are open from hell to roam freely. It is unsafe to take new born outside, it is unsafe for women to go out etc etc. Is it true and if it is then can someone share some reference or is it just a myth.

Answer (score 1):

Holy Prophet saww said:
لا عدوى ولا طيرة ولا هامة ولاصفر
There is no superstitious owl, bird, no star-promising rain, no bad omen in the month of Safar. [Sahih Bukhari, Hadith 5707]

لا عدوى ولا صفر ولا غول
There is no bad omen in the month of Safar and no Ghouls (evil spirits). [Sahih Muslim, Hadith 2222]

Comment: Thanks for the reference! What would one say to people who believes in not going out or takings new born out in the month and particles Islam

Comment: we should gave up those ridiculous believes that against the teaching of islam and we should practice islam not by our own false believes but according to quran, sunnah and actions of sahaba r.a

Answer (score -1):

This is pure falacy. All months are Allah's and Safar Month is not of bad omen as some people talk. This is an old falsehood spread in certain societies and has nothing to do with reality. Some say not to have a nikah or not to start a new venture in this month. This all is superstitious and it is not correct view whatsoever. And this Jinn idea is even more obnoxious.

Small children should be brought in before the Mukrooh time before Maghrib and can be let out again later.

Comment: okay i get a down vote for stating a fact? okay. bring forth a proof that month of safar has any bad omen attached to then.